# Append columns on the right to an awk file after matching a pattern

Tags: perl, bash, unix, scripting, awk

I have two files one of them is just a column vector such as :

```
1x23
1y21
1z21
1z25
```

and other is a matrix of the form

```
1x23 1x24 1y21 1y22 1y25 1z22 class
2000 3000 4000 5000 6000 7000 Yes
1500 1200 1100 1510 1410 1117 No
```

First I want to find which rows in first file matches with the first row in the second file. Second I want to copy columns of second file matching the ones in first file and append them to second file. So, since 1x23, 1y21 matches I want to copy those two columns in the second and append it before the class variable.

I want my result to be

```
1x23 1x24 1y21 1y22 1y25 1z22 1x23 1y21 class
2000 3000 4000 5000 6000 7000 2000 4000 Yes
1500 1200 1100 1510 1410 1117 1500 1100 No
```

I used perl to code it using for loops of 3 but since data is very big, it crashed. I think there should be efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one-liner:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next}FNR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(a[$i])k[i]}{for(x in k)$NF= sprintf("%s ",$x) $NF}7' f1 f2
```

better readable version:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next}
     FNR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(a[$i])k[i]}
     {for(x in k)
          $NF= sprintf("%s ",$x) $NF}7' f1 f2
```

output:

```
1x23 1x24 1y21 1y22 1y25 1z22 1y21 1x23 class
2000 3000 4000 5000 6000 7000 4000 2000 Yes
1500 1200 1100 1510 1410 1117 1100 1500 No
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ( $matrix, @cols ) = pop;
my %headings = map { chomp; $_ => 1 } <>;

push @ARGV, $matrix;
while (<>) {
    my @array = split;
    @cols = grep $headings{ $array[$_] }, 0 .. $#array if $. == 1;
    splice @array, -1, 0, @array[@cols];
    print "@array\n";
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl vectorFile matrixFile [>outFile]`

Output on your datasets:

```
1x23 1x24 1y21 1y22 1y25 1z22 1x23 1y21 class
2000 3000 4000 5000 6000 7000 2000 4000 Yes
1500 1200 1100 1510 1410 1117 1500 1100 No
```

A hash is created using the entries in the vector file.  The column positions of all of the entires that can be found on the first line of the matrix file are saved in `@col`.  The matching column entries from the `split` matrix line are inserted just before the last element of the `split` matrix line.  Finally, the new line is `print`ed.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a long winded but IMHO clear approach.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $data, '<', 'data.txt');

# read first row from the data file
my $line = <$data>;
chomp $line;

# create a list of columns
my @cols = split / /, $line;

# create hash with column indexes
my %colindex;
my $i = 0;
foreach my $colname (@cols) {
        $colindex{$colname} = $i++;
}

# Save last column ('class')
my $lastcol = pop @cols;

# get input (column names)
open(my $input, '<', 'input.txt');
my @colnames = <$input>;
close $input;

# append column names to array if there is a match
foreach (@colnames) {
        chomp;
        if (exists $colindex{$_}) {
                push @cols, $_;
        }
}

# Restore the last column
push @cols, $lastcol;

# Now process your data
open(my $out, '>', 'output.txt');

# write the header column
print $out join(" ", @cols), "\n";

while ($line = <$data>) {
        chomp $line;
        my @l = split / /, $line;
        foreach my $colname (@cols) {
                print $out $l[$colindex{$colname}], " ";
        }
        print $out "\n";
}

close $out;
close $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your Perl code would crash. I'd suggest the following algorithm that runs in constant memory (probably more readable when implemented in Perl than in AWK):

- Read first file and build a list of column names
- Read 1st line of the data file (with actual header)
- Intersect two lists to produce a list of *column indices*
- Read *one* line of a data file and split by columns
- Create a new array of column values by indexing it using the list of "required" column indices you built in step 3. Output it.
- Repeat last 2 steps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
awk -f app.awk file1.txt file2.txt
```

where `file1.txt` is your first file, `file2.txt` is the second file, and `app.awk` is

```
NR==FNR {
    key[$0]++
    next
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        C[FNR,i]=$i
}

END {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
        if (C[1,i] in key) 
            k[++j]=i                
    nc=j
    for (j=1; j<=FNR; j++) {
        for (i=1; i<NF; i++) 
           printf "%s%s",C[j,i],OFS     
        for (i=1; i<=nc; i++) 
           printf "%s%s",C[j,k[i]],OFS      
        printf "%s%s",C[j,NF],RS
    }
}
```